# JQuery/CSS - smooth change height of wrapping-DIV

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a bunch of DIVs nested in a wrapper-DIV

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner_1"></div>
    <div id="inner_2"></div>
    <div id="inner_3"></div>
</div>
```

every inner-DIV has a different height. I do show/hide the inner DIVs via fadeIn/fadeOut(), so the height of the wrapper jumps from small (inner_1) to high (inner_2) to wrap the inner-DIVs as they are shown.

Is there a simple way to animate the height of the wrapper-DIV, so it would slide smooth to fit the inner-DIV-height?

here a link to a example:
https://jsfiddle.net/a3wvxcuq/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a number in milliseconds to the `.show()` and `.hide()` methods and the divs will smoothly transition to the new dimensions.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3ygx1q20/3/)**

So that is just pointing you in the right direction.

Now *the code is your canvas and you are the artist* ;)

So another way that looks flashy : **[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/3ygx1q20/4/)**

Annd, it looks like we have a winner over here. **[Demo 3](https://jsfiddle.net/3ygx1q20/5/)**

Comment: You can also pass strings: 'slow', 'normal', 'fast'

Comment: @timenomad sure you can.

Comment: Just in case OP is lazy :D